# Email Using TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I want to configure the TeamCity in a way so that it can send out email notifications on various steps, like when it start the build, when it completes the taking latest source and on the failure (with attached logs), on success. Is it possible to configure email on any step we want.

Thanks for any help.